# Does lightning-record-form automatically support Standard Design Tokens for Communities?

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, lightning-community, design-tokens

This [lightning-record-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation) says that "Lightning Communities" are supported.

And communities support [Standard Design Tokens for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_tokens.htm) that allow e.g. the color scheme to be varied. Is that variation supported automatically in `lightning-record-form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an experiment where I have a `lightning-record-form` component presented in a Community it renders like this by default:

[image: Default design tokens image]

and like this when the [Design Tokens are edited](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_tokens.htm) so **confirming that the Design Token support is automatic** i.e. the SLDS class references can be left unchanged in the component and the changes come through:

[image: Modified design tokens image]